# WMD editor not working in edit form

Tags: php, wmd-editor

I am using WMD editor. [This](https://github.com/derobins/wmd) one.

It is working fine. But issue is, i want to get it working with edit form.

Right now i am getting html instead of markdown text.
My code is like following in my edit page.

```
<div id="wmd-editor" class="wmd-panel">
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
            <textarea id="wmd-input"><?php echo $row['description']?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel"></div>
    <div id="wmd-output" class="wmd-panel"></div>
```

Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: "Right now i am getting html instead of markdown text". If you are saving the HTML to `$row['description']` then that's what will be displayed. WMD doesn't convert HTML to Markdown. You'll need to store the Markdown in your database and output that to the editor instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: the repository is not maintained (and apparently has not been updated for over 7 years) so you should consider switching to an active branch. WMD was renamed to `Page Down` but there are many alternative editors out there you can use.

As [timclutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775731/timclutton) commented you are probably storing HTML in your database. WMD does not support conversion from HTML to Markdown. So the best solution would be to store the content as Markdown.

To do this change your *create* page. Since I have no code I'll just give you an example on how it could look:

```
<form action="/create" method="POST">
    <div id="wmd-editor" class="wmd-panel">
        <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
            <textarea name="content" id="wmd-input"></textarea>
        </div>
    <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel"></div>
    <div id="wmd-output" class="wmd-panel"></div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Server-side you can now store the content of `$_POST['content']` in your database and later output it exactly the way you are doing it right now to the *edit* page.

---

Lastly a security note from the [Page Down wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wiki):

> It should be noted that Markdown is not safe as far as user-entered input goes. Pretty much anything is valid in Markdown, in particular something like `<script>doEvil();</script>`. This PageDown repository includes the two plugins that Stack Exchange uses to sanitize the user's input; see the description of Markdown.Sanitizer.js below.

Comment: Actually i am storing the same thing in database as you described above. But when i came back to edit page with that value i can see html not the same like we can see on preview.

Comment: So you are storing Markdown? As I said the best option is probably to go with a newer and still maintained version of WMD (or PageDown as it is called now)

Comment: Yes i am storing Makdown. It is working fine if i want to display that on simple page. but not working properly with edit page. cause on edit page i am loading that text on wmd-editor. You can live example of Stack overflow. Try to edit your question. You will see proper text on wmd-editor. Not html, while in my case there is html

Comment: maybe simply the missing `;` in your PHP statement?

Comment: I am using like this. not getting your last comment. what is missing. <textarea id="wmd-input" name="content"><?php echo $questionData['question_desc'];?></textarea>